# Undeclared variables in sliced program

Tags: frama-c

When using the program slicer of Frama-C version Oxygen, I have the problem that the resulting slice uses undeclared variables.
I searched for existing postings to this topic before and found this:
http://bts.frama-c.com/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=806

There it is mentioned that the bug was fixed in the Nitrogen version of Frama-C. Maybe this change was not carried over to Oxygen? Like in the description of the existing posting it only happens for blocks with just one statement.
I cannot attach the example source code since it is from a customer project.

Comment: I understand that you cannot give the real source code, but maybe you could try to build a small example with only a `main` function and get the slice for the return value with `frama-c -slice-return main test.c -then-on 'Slicing export' -print`. I didn't manage to build such an example myself (the bug you mentioned should be fix in Oxygen).

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the exact steps described in the bug report you mention with Frama-C Oxygen (and csmith 2.0.0 for Csmith's runtime library), and everything works fine: it's very likely that you're experiencing another issue, but without the code, it's impossible to say more.

Comment: The code was produced by a code generator and I will try to extract the part which causes the problem.